# asp net mvc oracle database fail to retrieve data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, oracle

I have an Oracle DB set up, and the Database has a bunch of Views.
The view `GFL_BUYERS_ID_V` has 2 columns of `EMPLOYEE_ID` and `FULL_NAME`. The database is already filled before I created the mvc project.

I Add the database successfully and added the a schema `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("examplename.");` to my context because when I use SQL to retrieve data, I need to do:

`SELECT * FROM "examplename".GFL_BUYERS_ID_V`

for it to work, I assume that is what it's for. Apologies in advance I am new to .net, mvc and connecting databases.

The following crashes at the `.Select` and tells me that value cannot be null (I have no clue what is returning a null value, if I inspect values in context->`GFL_BUYERS_ID_V` when it breaks, in Local there are 0 values, and in Result View it contains all the appropriate one's, I assume this is relevant info but I don't know how to use it):

```
        var model = new EmployeeModel();

        using (var context = new OracleContext())
        {
            model.Buyers = context.GFL_BUYERS_ID_V.Select(s => new EmployeeModel.Buyer
            {
                BuyerId = s.EMPLOYEE_ID,
                FullName = s.FULL_NAME
            }).ToList();

        }
        return View(model);
```

this is my object:

```
public class EmployeeModel
{

    public int EmployeeModelId { get; set; }
    public List<Buyer> Buyers { get; set; }


    public class Buyer
    {

        public int BuyerId { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I know there is a connection to the database and I can query it via VB. I have fiddled enough with the connection string to know it is correct.

Edit: Scratch that I have no clue if my program is able to connect to the Database or not.

[Screen shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKJRK.png)

If you would like me to provide more information, I will be happy to, really want to make this one work.

Edit 2: This seems like some sick joke clearly it shows a count: [how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUcPB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in the Database server not the code. For some reason it used an old default schema variable that wasn't used for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an inner exception which is causing the ArgumentNullException?

You are definitely thinking along the right path, so I would break it down into manageable pieces:

1) confirm DB connectivity

2) confirm context is valid, which would most likely only be invalid if no DB connectivity

3) confirm GFL_BUYERS_ID_V is showing data

4) then do the projection to a different model

Comment: If I go to server explorer I can see that it's connected to the database, and I can use the query in VB to extract data from the view's. But even if I try to get context.GFL_BUYERS_ID_V.Count(). It's Still null, so I thought the schema was not what i thought it was so i commented it out. and if i run it without the schema I get the External component throwing exception. Both belong to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException
Otherwise i have no clue how to test if the program it self connects or how to get the View to show data through the program.

Comment: Can you pull back data or get a record count for other tables or views in the same schema?

Comment: I cannot, When I ether get a null value or an external component is throwing an exception. I am not 100% what they mean but as i get both of them based on adding or removing the schema (again i am not sure what it does). I am assuming the null value is because it's unable to determine the correct object since I can pull values from the view using SQL. So solving the external component error seems like the way forward, since I might be just messing up the command to extract information.